# IAuthorizationFilter deletes cookies

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, iauthorizationfilter

I have an MVC project i which the user can change language from a menu.
The controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string Language)
{
    Response.Cookies[SessionParams.LANGUAGE].Value = Language;
    Response.Cookies[SessionParams.LANGUAGE].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
}
```

and the Global.asax.cs code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies[SessionParams.LANGUAGE] != null)
    {
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Request.Cookies[SessionParams.LANGUAGE].Value);
    }
}
```

This works great. Now I added a class that implements IAuthorizationFilter to make sure that I can check whether the session is still valid before every request (FilterConfig.cs):

```
public class ConnectedUserValidAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
        string loginUrl = urlHelper.Action("Login", "Account");
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath != loginUrl)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionParams.CONNECTED_USER] == null)
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, after I add the filter to the global filters:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new ConnectedUserValidAuthorizationFilter());
}
```

Debugging shows that `Request.Cookies` in Global.asax.cs no longer holds value for the `language` cookie.

Removing the filter brings the value back.

Any idea how to resolve it? I tried moving the filter code to `Application_BeginRequest`, but the session does not exists yet in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing `IActionFilter` instead of `IAuthorizationFilter` interface, with the same logic used in `OnAuthorization`, inside `OnActionExecuting` function.

This seems more appropriate for the task, since `OnActionExecuting` is called before every Action request. It also seems to keep the cookies intact.